openssl version for ROS2 humble Win10
I am following the ROS 2 Humble documentation and it is required openssl v1.1.1t. In the official website I cannot find that versione cause EOL. How can I install it?

Raise an issue on the ROS.org site, not here, about fixing the documentation. It isn't clear who you are talking to (we aren't ROS, this is Stack Exchange). If your comment is a solution, then please post it as an answer (so that it may help others in future) and not as a comment. Comments can't not be voted upon. Please take the [tour] to better understand how Stack Exchange works. Thanks.

Does this answer your question? OpenSSL version problem in ROS2 Humble install for Windows. I answered this a few weeks ago.

I tryed to follow your answer but your linked guide was not so clear. I found a clearer one. Thank you :)

I found a good guide here to install openssl: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-WINDOWS.md

This is a bit of a link only answer. Whilst the repo is unlikely to disappear (as it is the OpenSSL repo, after all), it might be worth quoting the relevant part of the read me in your answer.

Please don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer (using the tick button). You can always change the accepted answer, later, if a better answer is posted. Thanks.
